# bluetooth not working after installing Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, bluetooth

I've tried hci0 reset. I've also tried resetting my bios. I've hard and soft unblocked. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling bluetooth. I've tried installing blueman but it does not open. I've tried running ubuntu on usb live mode, still bluetooth does not work. My BIOS is upto date. I've updated Ubuntu, tried Unity reset, but nothing works.

I still can't get my bluetooth working. It shows that it detects the hardware but still nothing.

My system runs on 4gigs ram, 64 bit Intel i3 M300 ,

Comment: Could you check if they are hardblocked and post the results of `rfkill list all`?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to use bluetooth on ubuntu 12.10 I have installed blueman as well and is a no go. I would like to use my jabra earphone bluetooth on skype. But I cannot pair it cause is just not working. When I open blueman it says "resource not ready"
I ran rfkill list all and i get this:
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

which not sure what it means... any advice will be appreciated.